# Taylor Series General Formulas

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

I'm looking at 2 different Wikipedia pages:

The formula [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor's_theorem#Taylor.27s_theorem_for_multivariate_functions) is different than the one given at the end of the section [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Taylor_series_in_several_variables).

Aside from the remainder, why choose one over the other? I'm assuming they're both correct? O and multivariate == multivariable?

The fact that two formulas are provided only adds to the complexity of figuring the whole thing out!

One other thing...how would each of these formulas change for a VECTOR function? They only provide the equations for scaler functions and I don't want to make a major mistake. As I said, it's already quite confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll find that if you compare these two formulas, they're exactly the same.  The second page differs only in that it gives you explicit examples of how a multivariable Taylor series would appear if you were to calculate it.  And yes, multivariate == multivariable.

For the second answer, there's more explanation involved.  Let's take a vector valued function with two variables, f(x,y) = (g(x,y)i + h(x,y)j).

The Taylor expansion of this function is

f(x,y)= f($x_0,y_0$) + $\begin{bmatrix} {\partial g \over \partial x} \ {\partial g \over \partial y} \\ {\partial h \over \partial x} \ {\partial h \over \partial y} \end{bmatrix}$  f($x_0,y_0$)($x-x_0$,$y-y_0$) + f($x_1,y_1$) + $H_f (x,y)$f($x_1, y_1$)($x-x_1, y-y_1$)...etc

It gets really time consuming to expand further but you get the idea.  Note that $H_f (x,y)$ is the Hessian matrix, ie 2nd order partials).

Comment: I'll give ya partial credit. I'm guessing the order of the terms ((x-a) term before or after) doesn't matter, cause they aren't "exactly" the same? I know if you change one thing in this index heavy notation it can mean a total different thing. I just want to be sure. Also, my last question on how to treat VECTOR functions?

Comment: They're not exactly the same, but they are functionally the same because multiplication is commutative inside the sigma.

Comment: @JHStromThank you for clearing that up!!